# vim-orgmode: unfold everything on file open by default

Tags: folding

Currently when I open files in org mode all the top level bullet points are folded.  I can see why this is an OK default for a lot of people, but I prefer all text unfolded initially.  Is there a simple configuration to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest is to put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set foldlevelstart=99
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `~/.vimrc` addition which only affects org-mode files:

```
autocmd FileType org setlocal foldlevel=99
```

Answer (score 0):

I turn folds off

```
set nofoldenable
```

And toggle them with `zi`. My auto-origami plugin (on github—link later) toggles the foldcolumn for me.